# How to refresh org file programatically

Tags: org-mode, save-excursion

I am using `spacemacs-light` theme in Emacs and love it.

In my spacemacs-light theme, some org-files open with bullets not hidden though. In those cases I go to the top of the file and hit `C-c C-c` to refresh my org-file. And then I go back to where I was via `C-u C-SPC`.

Now I would like to create an elisp function that does this in a single step and map it to a key.[^1] Here is my approach in Elisp:

```
(defun my-refresh-org-fle ()
  (interactive)
  (progn
    (set-mark-command nil)
    (beginning-of-buffer)
    (org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c)
    (pop-mark)))
```

But it does not work. It won't go back to where I was.

I guess I haven't quite understood the functions `set-mark-command` and `pop-mark`. Although I do understand the concept of the mark-ring, and I enjoy using it (love jumping back to where I was prior to jumping to other files).

---

[^1]: Of course I could start debugging as to why I have this behaviour in spacemacs-theme in Emacs 26.x, but I don't have the time to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track, but the standard elisp idiom for "go somewhere else in the buffer, do some stuff, and then go back to where you came from" is to use [`save-excursion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Excursions.html).

You can rewrite (and simplify!) your command as follows:

```
(defun my-refresh-org-fle ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c)))
```

As an aside, the docstring for `beginning-of-buffer` says:

> This function is for interactive use only;
> in Lisp code use `(goto-char (point-min))` instead.